# How to check for, specific but random in length, byte collection in c#?

Tags: c#, byte

I have a collection of encoded byte that has this format:

```
[keybyte1(random 5-10 bytes)][keybyte2(random 5-10 bytes)]...rest of encoded byte...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is: if a user input a key (5-10 characters), I can check whether the key is same as `keybyte1` or `keybyte2`. If same as `keybyte1` I want to fire event 1, and if it is same as `keybyte2` I want to fire event 2.

My question is: how to make a comparison of keybyte1 or 2 if they are both in random length with a code similar to this:

```
FileStream fsin = new FileStream(fin, FileMode.Open);                
byte[] buffer = new byte[(random 5-10)];
//check for keybyte1
fsin.Read(buffer, 0, (random 10-20));
if(buffer[0]=='0xsomething' || ... || buffer[9]=='0xsomething')
{
...event 1...
}

//check for keybyte2
//start from index 10 if keybyte1 is 10 bytes long
if(buffer[10]=='0xsomething' || ... || buffer[19]=='0xsomething')
{
...event 2...
}
```

So far, the code above is only effective if `keybyte1` and `keybyte2` is in a fixed length. Is there any way around this?

Comment: The frell are you trying to do? o_O Why not `var length1 = random.Next(5, 10); var length2 = random.Next(5, 10); var buffer = new byte[length1 + length2];`? And then work with the now "fixed" (known) lengths?

Comment: What you are asking sounds impossible. If a user types in something that matches keybyte2, you won't be able to compare it because you don't know how long keybyte1 is, and therefore you don't know where keybyte2 starts in your byte array. Unless there's something I've misunderstood, you need to fix the lengths of the keybytes (or provide some way of telling how long they are) to make the problem solvable.

Comment: @SimonRobinson: it's possible thanks to your hint to tell how long they are. I made a format of `[length of keybyte1(as single byte)][length of keybyte2(also as single byte)][keybyte1(random 5-10 bytes)][keybyte2(random 5-10 bytes)]...rest of encoded byte...`.The length byte is a byte that I encoded from an integer(length of keybyte1 and keybyte2). With that "length" byte I was able to check it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Corak: i can't use a random on length for checking, since I must know the length for buffer by the time i need to do the checking.

Comment: If you use `length1` and `length2` like in my first comment, you can then use the same values to read from the FileStream `fsin.Read(buffer, 0, (length1 + length2));`

Comment: @Corak: yes, i know, that works for the checking buffer. But my real question is that, how to check if `user types something that matches keybyte2`, just like what Mr.Simon Robinson said in his comments. Thanks for your help though, and i have found the way around it.

Comment: "i have found the way around it." Okay. Still not sure what exactly you're trying to to or what the real problem is. If you have a `byte[] keybyte1` and a `byte[] keybyte2` then just comparing for `keybyte2` like `for(int i=0;i<keybyte2.Length;i++){ if (buffer[keybyte1.Length + i] != keybyte2[i]) { \\ don't do event 2 and jump to keybyte3 or whatever } } // do event 2`.